# What should I do if someone continuously attempt to login to my WordPress admin panel?

Tags: wordpress, security

I have a website which is developed using WordPress.

Since last 3 months someone continuously try to login to my WordPress Admin panel. They are using different IP address **EVERYTIME**. I think they are using : **brute force attack**

To security purpose I am using "Sucuri Security" plugin which is installed to my site and I have also installed "Limit Login Attempts"

From "Sucuri Security" plugin they send me a message after failed login :

**Message is look like this :**

> 1 failed login attempts (1 lockout(s)) from IP: 109.173.88.245
>
> Last user attempted: administrator
>
> 1 failed login attempts (1 lockout(s)) from IP: 37.194.196.180
>
> 1 failed login attempts (1 lockout(s)) from IP: 83.174.209.143

Now, In last 45 minutes they attempted to login 31 times.

What should I do now ?

Answer (score 3):

The first and most obvious answer: Use a long, strong password (random letters, numbers, and preferably other characters too).

If you are doing so, the chance they will get access to your site in this particular way is close to zero.

Consider the number of login-attempts on a per hour, or per year basis:

> 31 logins / 45 mins = aproximately 0.7 logins per minute.
>
> Multiply that by the number of minuts in a year:
>
> 60 mins * 24 hours * 365 days = approximately 367'920 login attempts
>   in the space of a year.

For a good password, this number is so small that the "brute force attack" will be practically insignificant.

I won't blame you if you still want to improve your security though. If so, you should look into options for [two factor authentication for WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Two_Step_Authentication) (i.e. a system where some extra piece of information is required to confirm your identity before you can log in).

**PS:** I haven't tried any of these personally, but if I was in your shoes, I'd probably give the [Google Authenticator plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-authenticator/) a shot.

Comment: Is there any way to know from which country attacker is doing this ?

Comment: In theory an IP address can tell you something about where an attempted connection is coming from, but that is easily circumvented by using a proxy - so *possibly, yes*, but not likely in a trustworthy way. =)

Answer (score 2):

Use strong passwords. :)

This type of thing happens all the time, not just against websites, people try to brute force just about anything, smtp, pop3 and imap servers, ssh servers, commonly used applications like Wordpress, etc.

The most important thing is to make sure that if password authentication is used, those passwords (all of them!) resist brute force attempts. This means having enough entropy, ie. being long enough and from multiple character classes, not using dictionary words, etc. A 10 characters long random
password with letters, capital letters and numbers is pretty much infeasible to brute force.

In addition to that, you can implement active monitoring of some sort, banning the user and/or the request IP address for a while after several unsuccessful password attempts, etc. These countermeasures raise the bar for an attacker, but a strong enough non-dictionary password is probably good enough anyway for a Wordpress site. (So it's a risk-based thing. If the value you can lose is $10000, you don't want to spend $50000 to protect it.)

Answer (score 0):

One of my sites is constantly bombarded with failed login attempts. The IP addresses keep changing - I do have a blacklist but I'm not sure how much value there is in maintaining that if the IP addresses are always changing.

I could whitelist the admin to allow access only from a specific IP range; I feel this is very restrictive for the nature of the website - a free service. Here's a screenshot of thousands of emails I get for this site regarding failed login attempts - consistent for well over a year if not more.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same login attack email inform (almost 50 attacks one day) and solved via disable `xml-rpc.php`

Add this to theme or child theme `function.php`:

```
//disable XML-RPC

add_filter('xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false');
```

Comment: What does this do exactly? Thanks!